# git ignore /* and !/**/somefile* not exclude properly

Tags: git, gitignore

my git repo directory like this:

```
--ignore_dir/
----dir2/
------ignorea3.txt
----aaa.txt
----ignorea2.txt
--ignorea1.txt
--ignore1.txt
--.gitignore
```

`.gitignore` file like this:

```
/*
!/**/ignorea*.txt
```

with `git status`, it output:

```
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ignorea1.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

My question is why it not tracking files: `ignore_dir/dir2/ignorea3.txt` and `ignore_dir/ignorea2.txt`

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Thanks @RomainValeri and @torek,
I got a complex way to achieve this, by edit gitignore file:

```
/*
!/ignore_dir/
/ignore_dir/*
!/ignore_dir/dir2/

/ignore_dir/dir2/*
!/ignore_dir/dir2/ignorea*.txt
!/ignore_dir/ignorea*.txt
```

It give a explicit tracking every parent level directory of the `ignorea*.txt`.

Besides, this will not work:

```
/*
!**/ignorea*.txt
```

Hope someone could give a elegant way!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5533050/1256452

Comment: Thanks a lot for the posted solution, I'll study that in detail. It drove me insane yesterday!

Comment: @RomainValeri, pleasure it can make some help. I think make a clean project is important more then complex git skill.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) :

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**

(emphasis mine)

So, since directories `ignore_dir` and `dir2` are excluded by the first pattern, reincluding files inside them in the next line won't work.

---

Failed attempt :

```
# ignore eveything
/*

# reintroduce "ignore_dir" directory
!/ignore_dir

# reintroduce "dir2" directory
!/ignore_dir/dir2

# reintroduce any ignorea*.txt file in any directory
!/**/ignorea*.txt
```

But as torek [mentions below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281087/git-ignore-and-somefile-not-exclude-properly/55281735?noredirect=1#comment97299487_55281735), this isn't working. To be improved.

Comment: hi, thanks. It's there are standard way to hand such situation, tracking all `ignorea*.txt`?

Comment: @LoranceChen Been trying everything in the last half hour, but in vain. I'm sorry not having found, but I thank you a lot for all I learned during the process :-) And I'll be very happy to see what others will propose to solve it.

Comment: Remember that Git is doing a recursive tree walk of all the directories in your work-tree. For all *other* operations (not for .gitignore) Git just says to itself: *oh, subdirectory, look inside because all I care about is files*. But for matching a `.gitignore` rule Git tries the subdirectory itself: if it matches, it *doesn't bother scanning the subdirectory at all* and hence never recurses into it to find files in it that would be un-ignored. You can defeat this with a simple `!**/` rule if you put it in the right place, but this does completely kill off the optimization.